# Save/read a string on a struct

Tags: c++

For a school project, i had to do a program that would save movies name and other details, so later on we could see it or edit.
I used structs and char variables on it, and wrote to the file on binary (fwrite) and its all working right, but since the char type variables have a limited space i wanted to create the same program but with string instead of char.

so i made a small program just to test it out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct MULTIMEDIA_FILME
{
string nome;
string tipo;
int ano;
string  descricao;
};

int main()
{
using namespace std;
struct MULTIMEDIA_FILME filmes ;

fstream myFile("filme.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios_base::app);
ofstream filme_txt;
filme_txt.open("filme.txt");

cout << "Nome do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes.nome;
filme_txt << filmes.nome << endl;
cout << "Tipo do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes.tipo;
filme_txt << filmes.tipo << endl;
cout << "Ano do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes.ano;
filme_txt << filmes.ano << endl;
cout << "Descricao do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes.descricao;
filme_txt << filmes.descricao << endl;

filme_txt.close();

}
```

back on the other program i had 2 files, 1 for the movie counter (where it would save how many movies i had) and other file to save name, type, year, and a description.
now the problem im facing is, how could i save various movies and call them by the counter. 
my idea was using "seekg" function everytime i add a new movie so it would be written on the end of the file and not replace other. but is that the right way to do it? and about the counter, there is any idea of how could i do it.
i dont want to make the file binary, for further porpuses.

EDIT1: updated the code using now ios_base::app ,but the program still dont write on the end of the file. when i add a new item it just replaces the old one.

Comment: better work in memory and write the file only when necessary; did you already think of what to do when you will have to remove films?

Comment: In the real world, what you want is probably to use [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/).

Comment: Open with `std::ios_base::app` to write on the end of the file.

Comment: `| ios::trunc` is your bug.

Comment: @OznOg could you give me a idea of what you are talking of working in memory. and i wouldnt had to remove the movies because the main objective of the program is to make a track of the things you saw, so it would only be needed to edit some camps